# How to import an object from another javascript file?

Tags: javascript, object, import

I'd like to create a config file like this:

```
var config = { some stuff }
```

and import it to my main javascript file.

I know it is possible to import a function, this is part of the ES6 specification (but not supported yet?) and I can import some modules in node.js without any problems.

But what about importing an object? Is there any way to do it?

I try to make my config not a global variable.

Maybe this is not a good idea and there is a better way?

Comment: Config files are data, not logic. Store it as JSON and load it with a file system reader.

Comment: Yes, but my config is not formated in JSON at the moment

Comment: So change it so that it is.

Comment: Sure, this is a good option. I'll  think about it. thx